# Share PDF file on Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I know about share image or text on Facebook but if i want to share any file such as pdf is there any way to upload that file on facebook.
-Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot upload documents on Facebook**..only image/video types are upload able.

Comment: if ..you want to be social..you can send to dropbox..email documents.